# How to increase request timeout for rocks connection?

Tags: packages, sitecore-rocks

I'm getting below error when trying to build package using Sitecore Rocks. While building package it takes some time so the connection is getting timed out.

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9909995. Increase the timeout value passed to the request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. localhost/.../service2.asmx has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:59:998000

I have tried updating `compilation` to `debug="true"` and also tried updating timeout attributes on `SitecoreApplicationCenter` under `<system.serviceModel>` thinking it will work but still I get timeout.

Comment: Are you using HTTPS on the site you're connecting to? If there's an HTTP->HTTPS redirect set up, Sitecore Rocks may time out because of that. Disable the redirect in your development environment and the issue will be solved.

Comment: Site is on local system only and it is HTTP. Other features work fine of Rocks. Only `Build` package takes time because package defined by me has lots of items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the connection xml under

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Sitecore\Sitecore.Rocks.VisualStudio\Connections
```

Open the xml file and edit the timeout attributes as needed.

[image]

```
<binding hostName="sc81" useWindowsAuth="false"
userName="sitecore\admin" password="b21d95ba8b8afb0d" 
dataService="Hard Rock Web Service"
webRootPath="E:\SC81\Website"     
description="" isRemoteSitecore="false" 
automaticallyUpdate="true" isHidden="false"
hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
openTimeout="00:01:00" 
closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
maxReceivedMessageSize="16777216" maxBufferSize="16777216" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxStringContentLength="16777216" transferMode="Buffered" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" proxyAddress="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup the configuration here: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Sitecore\Sitecore.Rocks\Connections

Comment: Please include more detailed instructions on increasing the timeout setting.