# Sitecore rocks timeout error

Tags: sitecore-rocks

After installing Sitecore.Rocks.2.1.86, tried to create new connection through VS2017, but getting timeout error. [image]

Any help with the above would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you follow the answer from https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/how-to-increase-request-timeout-for-rocks-connection

Comment: I tried the URL too, but I couldn't find any XML files under 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Sitecore\Sitecore.Rocks.VisualStudio\Connections'. I tried reinstall Sitecore Rocks still have same problem.

Comment: Can you try C:\Users\{youraccountname}\AppData\Local\Sitecore\Sitecore.Rocks.VisualStudio\Connections. Replace the Administrator with your folder name

Comment: Yes... I did, I couldn't find any XML files

Comment: Have you already tried to create the connection in Sitecore Rocks?

Comment: Yes I tried, but I got timeout error, then I referred above referred URL, But I couldn't able to see the xml file as specified in the reference URL, So again I reinstall Sitecore rocks, but still I couldn't able to see the any xml file in the specified path, still getting the time out error.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to change the authorization of your website as described in this blogpost by Rob Ahnemann? 
XHTML

```
<location path="sitecore/shell/WebService">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="?,*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

http://www.rockpapersitecore.com/2017/10/sitecore-rocks-with-sitecore-9/

Comment: Yes, but no luck...

Comment: I assume you have tried both data provider (hard and soft)